# Objects in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is what code looks like:

```
var figury = new Array("kwadrat", "kolo", "trojkat_rownoboczny", "trojkat_prostokatny", "heksagon", "trapez");
var kolory = new Array("blue", "green", "red", "yellow");

var losowanie_figur = function(wylosowane_figury) {
    for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        wylosowane[i] = { figura: figury[losowe[i]] };
}
var losowanie_kolorow = function(wylosowane_kolory) {
    for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        wylosowane[i] = { kolor: kolory[losowe[i]] };
}
```

What I want to do is to update the array with the color values but what I get is that the previous values are being overwritten. I'm using a random f

This is what I get:

```
{ '0': { kolor: 'red' },
  '1': { kolor: 'green' },
  '2': { kolor: 'yellow' },
  '3': { kolor: 'blue' } }
```

And what I really wanted is:

```
{ '0': { figura: 'kwadrat', kolor: 'green' },
  '1': { figura: 'heksagon', kolor: 'red' },
  '2': { figura: 'trapez', kolor: 'blue' },
  '3': { figura: 'trojkat_prostokatny', kolor: 'yellow' } }
```

Comment: You basically want an array of objects. Keys are non-numeric, and the order is trivial.

Comment: You keep setting the entry instead of modifying an entry. But

Comment: Do you really want an array of objects, or do you want an object that maps figures to colors, like `{kwadrat: 'green', heksagon: 'red', ...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var losowanie_kolorow = function(wylosowane_kolory){
for(var i=0;i<=3;i++)
    wylosowane[i].kolor =kolory[losowe[i];
}
```

You need to set the properties on the objects, rather than setting the whole array value to be a new object.

As an aside you never set up `wylosowane` in this code, I'm assuming that was cut to simplify?  You also never use the parameters of the functions.  Since thats the case its probably better to not have the params at all.

Also its generally considered best practice to declare arrays as

```
var kolory = ["blue", "green", "red", "yellow"];
```

rather than

```
var kolory = new Array("blue", "green", "red", "yellow");
```

Most people consider it more readable, and it avoids some weird edge cases (`new Array(3)` for instance, creates an empty array of length 3, rather than an array of length 1 with 3 at the 0 index)

Comment: yes, I've slightly shortened the code. Your answer worked perfectly.

`var losowe = new Array;
var wylosowane = new Object;

var losowanie = function(rozmiar_tablicy) {
 losowe = [];
 while(losowe.length < 4){
  var wylosowana = Math.floor(Math.random() * (rozmiar_tablicy - 1 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
  var znaleziona = false;
  for(var i=0;i<=losowe.length;i++){
   if(losowe[i]===wylosowana){
    znaleziona = true;
    break;
   }
  }
  if(!znaleziona)
   losowe[losowe.length]=wylosowana;
 }
 return losowe;
};`

`losowanie_figur(losowanie(6));
losowanie_kolorow(losowanie(4));

console.log(wylosowane);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore JS to achieve something similar to this: http://underscorejs.org/#zip

```
var figury = new Array("kwadrat", "kolo", "trojkat_rownoboczny", "trojkat_prostokatny", "heksagon", "trapez");
var kolory = new Array("blue", "green", "red", "yellow");
var combined = _.zip(figury, kolory);
```

Hope this helps